# WKWebview evaluateJavaScript - returns unsupported type

Tags: javascript, swift, swift4, wkwebview

Im trying to check whether a button exist within the html or not with the following code:

```
 webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('btn-start-solo')") { (result, error) in
        print(error)
        if error == nil {
            print(result!)
        }
    }
```

however I keep getting:

```
Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported return type when execute javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624174/unsupported-return-type-when-execute-javascript)